# GNex factory reset apparently doesn't write anything and I'm not able to update

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, factory-reset, fastboot

my gnex (maguro) started rebooting frequently (like every 30 seconds). I hope is not an hardware fault and now I'm trying to restore a factory image so I can rule out any custom rom-derived problems.

I'm trying to flash yakju-jwr66y the problem is when I flash the bootloader and radio everyithing is ok but when it reboots to install the rest of the system the bootloader and radio are still not updated!

If I try to update manually the bootloader this is what I get:

Code:

```
wax@pasifae:~/Scaricati/yakju-jwr66y (2)$ fastboot flash bootloader bootloader-maguro-primemd04.img
sending 'bootloader' (2308 KB)...
OKAY [  0.308s]
writing 'bootloader'...
OKAY [  7.971s]
finished. total time: 8.279s
wax@pasifae:~/Scaricati/yakju-jwr66y (2)$ fastboot reboot-bootloader
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.006s]
finished. total time: 0.006s
```

But the bootloader version is still the primemd03! The same goes with the radio.
What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the EMMMC is fried. The only solution is RMA